# texstudio: Disable scrolling after compilation in the built-in PDF viewer?

Tags: texstudio, viewers

How can I disable scrolling after compilation in the built-in PDF viewer?

I noticed that I can turn off "scrolling follows cursor" and "cursor follows scrolling", but this does not affect scrolling after compilation.

Comment: Probably you are using a shortcut for `pdflatex` + `view output` and then the viewer goes to the current part of the text. Try this: move to a different part of your document and just press F6 (to run `pdflatex`). Check if the viewer will scroll to the current part.

Comment: You can configure the commands to be used. Go to Option menu and then Configure. You can change the shortcuts also.

Comment: @Sigur, if you just run pdflatex (F6), then the PDF in the viewer doesn't update, right?  I think florian wants the PDF in the viewer to update following the build, but wants the viewer to remain on the same page number it was on prior to the build rather than being scrolled to whatever part of the PDF corresponds to the cursor's current position in the editor.

Comment: Note that this behavior cannot be achieved by toggling the two lock icons in the bottom of the viewer ("Cursor follows scrolling" and "Scrolling follows cursor"), which change the behavior between builds.